# C# - WPF - Changing the inheritance of my window

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

Hello StackOverflow community,

I got a question regarding the inheritance of the WPF windows.

If you create a new window it inherits from System.Windows.Window - so let's just say: I want that every window that I use have following code in his constructor:

```
MinHeight = Height;
MinWidth = Width;
```

So my first attempt was that I create a new class called **BaseWindow** and put the code block into the constructor of **BaseWindow** (this method I also often used for forms application and it worked there).

```
namespace MyProject.Classes
{
    public class BaseWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public BaseWindow()
        {
            MinHeight = Height;
            MinWidth = Width;
        }
    }
}
```

My **BaseWindow** class is now existing and now I let my window **wndLogin** inherit from the **BaseWindow** - so something like that:

```
using MyProject.Classes;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class wndLogin : BaseWindow
    {

        public wndLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeWindow();
        }

        private void InitializeWindow()
        {
            // Initializing window specific stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that this class is partial, so I also changed the inheritance on the other part of the class in the file **wndLogin.g.i.cs** - it says there, that this file is an auto generated file and should not be edited.

```
namespace MyProject {
    /// <summary>
    /// wndLogin
    /// </summary>
    public partial class wndLogin : System.Windows.Window, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {
        // auto generated stuff here
    }
}
```

When I edit it anyway it replaces my custom inheritance with the standard inheritance → **System.Windows.Window** after debugging the project.

---

Is there a way to disable this automatic generated code or to tell Visual Studio that it should use an other class for inheritance?

---

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Don't hand-edit `wndLogin.g.i.cs`, it is generated automatically (as you found out).

In order to do this, you need to also change the XAML file to use your window:

```
<local:BaseWindow x:Class="MyNamespace.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</local:BaseWindow>
```

Notice the `<local:BaseWindow ...` instead of `Window`. If your `BaseWindow` class is in an entirely different namespace, you'll need to specify that in the xaml:

```
<baseWindowNs:BaseWindow x:Class="MyNamespace.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        xmlns:baseWindowNs="clr-namespace:MyProject.Classes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</baseWindowNs:BaseWindow>
```

The key line being the namespace qualifier: `xmlns:baseWindowNs="clr-namespace:MyProject.Classes"`, and then use your namespace name in place of `local` from the first sample.

The only other change needed is the `WindowName.xaml.cs` file to inherit from the new base class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : BaseWindow
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Alternatively (and more in-line with WPF MVVM conventions) you could create a base view model that has those properties and bind your window class `Height` and `Width` to those viewmodel properties. Personally that is how I would approach this rather than create a new base class for windows.

Comment: This seems to work - but I got a little problem over here:

My BaseWindow class is in an other namespace, how can I tell XAML where it is?

**local:MyProject.Classes.BaseWindow**,
**MyProject.Classes.BaseWindow** or
**local:BaseWindow** aren't working... :)

And thanks for the quick answer by the way!

Comment: @Kevin I modified the answer to show how to specify a different namespace.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! I'm gonna look up how a viewmodel is working in WPF and how I'll get this done. :') I usually work with a BaseForm (or in WPF: BaseWindow) class, where all my forms are inheriting from. :)

Comment: Update: It works! Thank you really really much Ron Beyer! :-)